# What should be inside onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a question. I have a delete function in my external javascript (ajax) that I am using to fire so that the delete query in my PHP file will be executed.

What I want to find out is what should be inside the onreadystatechange function. There is a previous function before that which just displays the table. Inside the onreadystatechange function is

```
document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

So now I am confused, do I put the same thing or? How do I get the query to execute and the table to display the new results after a record has been removed?

function.js Javascript file:

```
function deleteThis(count){

 var name = document.getElementById("row"+count).innerHTML;
 var page = "database.php";
 var parameters = 'name='+name+'&action=delete'
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')==true){

 if(xmlhttp==null){
  alert("Your browser does not support ajax!");
  return false;
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
 //what should be in here
 };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", page+"?"+parameters, true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
}
```

Inside the database.php file:

```
                      .
                      .
               Other lines of code
                      .
                      .


 function deleteRow($name){
    $table_info = "info";

  $query_string = "delete from $table_info where id = '$name'";
  $result = @mysql_query($query_string);
 }
?>

<?php
  $name = rtrim($_REQUEST['name']);
  $action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

  if($action=="delete"){
   echo deleteRow($name);
  }
  else{
   echo update_database();
  }
?>
```

Comment: *"what should be inside the onreadystatechange function"* The code that process the server response.

Comment: I see. So what if I want to display the same table but with the latest result, meaning after deletion. I can't seem to delete the row in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

> Returns a EventHandler that is called whenever the readyState attribute changes. The callback is called from the user interface thread.

So when the `readyState` is changed, you can see the status of the request in this attribute.

> 0     UNSENT  open() has not been called yet.
>
> 1     OPENED  send() has been called.
>
> 2     HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
>
> 3     LOADING     Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
>
> 4     DONE    The operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the server response, and some test if the ajax is success or error

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  //what should be in here
   if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) { 
         console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) // response of your server
   } else {
        console.log("Error")
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info and help guys. By the way, what I was referring to was literally what was inside:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
 document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
};
```